# Remove Background on Specific Media Query

Tags: css, responsive-design

I want my background to go away when a specific screen size is met. 
Here's my CSS code..

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 479px) {
        .videohome { background-image: none; background-color:#fefefe; }
    }

.videohome {
        background: url(images/extras/homevideobg.png) repeat-x #e6e6e6;
    }
```

Then when i view it on Google Chrome with a screen size of 479px; the background is still there..

Here's the Inspect Element,

Inspect Element --  Google Chrome

```
www.mysite.com/media="all"
.videohome {
background: url(images/extras/homevideobg.png) repeat-x #e6e6e6;
}
___________________________________

www.mysite.com/media="all"
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 0px)
.videohome {
background-image: none;  <-- this part is Striked Through
background-color: #fefefe;  <-- this part is Striked Through
}
```

What i'm doing wrong? Is the order important?

Comment: Order is important,  else this will never work.  Remember,  stylesheet is cascading in nature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the order of the selector(s) is important since the stylesheet is read from top to bottom (that's the cascading nature of CSS). This means that you would have to place the media query CSS below the initial declaration if you want it to be overridden.

If changing the order of the CSS doesn't solve your problem, then the issue is [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). Just increase the [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the selector inside of the media query in order to effectively override the other CSS.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2zmK/)

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 0px) {
    .videohome {
        background: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  Put the initial declaration before any queries, and I usually write queries in descending order of width.

Comment: so the order will be 1st normal css, 2nd desktop media query, 3rd tablets, 4th is mobile ..

Comment: @JeremiLiwanag http://www.smashingmagazine.com/responsive-web-design-guidelines-tutorials/

Answer (score 4):

Often, you'll have to use `!important` in the rule in a specific media query to override the rule defined outside of any queries.

For instance, in your media query, try this:

```
.videohome { background-image: none !important; background-color:#fefefe; }
```

Answer (score 2):

However, order is important. Also, make sure you are not setting another background to your .videohome after any mediaqueries. SO mediaqueries usually always go last. If things get ugly remember the **!important;** keyword after any css statement, but very careful with it as it usually is best not to use unless absolutely necessary.